# Are all least square filters adaptive?

Tags: filter-design, adaptive-filters

Are least square filters, or filters that minimize error energy, the same as least mean square adaptive filters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR:** No, they are not necessarily the same.

---

**Gory Details**

Least squares is just an optimization technique. It is used in a variety of ways.

For filter **design** it is used to select that realizable filter $H_r(e^{j\omega})$ that most closely matches, in the least squares sense, the ideal required filter response $H_i(e^{j\omega})$:
$$
H_r(e^{j\omega}) = \arg \min \parallel H_r - H_i \parallel_2  
$$
where $\parallel \cdot \parallel_2$ is the 2-norm or least-squares norm.

This sort of filter $H_r$ is not adaptive. That is, it doesn't change once it has been designed.

Adaptive filters may also use the least squares criterion, but in a different way: as part of the **adaptation step**.

Adaptive filters start off with initial filter coefficients $\vec{w}_o[0]$ and then use an update:
$$
\vec{w}_o[n] =\vec{w}_o[n-1] + \mu g[n-1]
$$
where $\mu$ is the step-size and $g$ is the gradient of the least squared error  surface in the direction of the minimum (from our current "location" of $\vec{w}_o[n-1]$).

Here, $g$ is determined by our error criterion: least squares. This means: 
$$
\parallel \vec{w}_{\tt opt} - \vec{w}_o \parallel_2
$$
where $ \vec{w}_{\tt opt}$ is the unknown optimal (minimizing) solution.

Answer (score 2):

In complement to Peter, yes or no, depending on what you want to be adaptive to. Let us assume the world is made of signals AND systems. **Signals pass** (by temporary existence), **while systems remain** (by essence). I acknowledge that one may swap these philosophical terms, on instance.

In most lectures, systems are somehow considered  invariant, while signals can change a lot, often according to some ordinal variable (time, space, temperature, etc.). In this context, most methods adapt modeled systems according to a given target, under some assumptions. Any "least" method is a form of adaptivity, yet with respect to some "invariant" template.

The common notion of adaptivity is generally thought with respect to a variation of the data along the ordinal variable, where the actual model is, within a given formalism (spectral, auto-regressive, moving average, etc.), adapted to the actual properties of a chunk of the signal.

However, the actual situation is more blurry than that. However, from a corpus point of view, **all least square filters are not adaptive**, as the existence, or the dependence on some ordinal variable is not mandatory.